# Why can't this method infer its parameter type from the Predicate<T> parameter in the signature?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Why can't my calls to `ValueOrDefault` infer the type based on usage?

```
class Foo {
  public string ValueA { get; set; }
  public int ValueB { get; set; }
}

class Example {
  // neither Func<T,bool> or Predicate<T> works
  Func<Func<Foo,T>,T> ValueOrDefault<T>(Foo orig, Foo toReplace, Predicate<T> replaceIf) {
    return getValue => {
      var origValue = getValue(orig);
      var replaceWith = getValue(toReplace);
      return replaceIf(origValue) ? replaceWith : origValue;
    };
  }

  public Response SaveSomeStuff(int clientId, Foo toSave) {
    Foo fromDb = _dbService.GetFooByClientId(clientId);
    var valueA = ValueOrDefault(toSave, fromDb, string.IsNullOrEmpty)(f => f.ValueA);
    var valueB = ValueOrDefault(toSave, fromDb, i => i == 0)(f => f.ValueB);

    var request = new Request {
      ValueA = valueA,
      ValueB = valueB,
    };
    return GetResponse(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# compiler is not allowed to use the return value of a method to resolve the method itself, including any type inference.

Neither the method group `string.IsNullOrEmpty` nor the lambda `i => i == 0` provide sufficient information to derive `T` in the `ValueOrDefault<T>` call. The compiler cannot use the fact that you are passing `f.ValueA` of type `string` to the first `Func`, and `f.ValueB` of type `int` to the second `Func`, because these are return values of the `ValueOrDefault<T>` method.

If you provide a type, for example, by making a separate variable of the correct type, you would be able to compile your code:

```
Predicate<string> isNullEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty;
var valueA = ValueOrDefault(toSave, fromDb, isNullEmpty)(f => f.ValueA);
Predicate<int> isZero = i => i == 0;
var valueB = ValueOrDefault(toSave, fromDb, isZero)(f => f.ValueB);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/JGB0eW)

Comment: Thanks for the catch. that was an accident in simplifying the problem from the original code

Comment: your explanation is confusing to me. section 7.5.2.12 "inferred return type" in the c# 5.0 language specification clearly states that it can infer the type based on the return type of the of the generic function. `var foo = SomeIEnumerable.Select(sie => sie.SomeProperty)` works with type inference based on the return type of the supplied function. This also works with `SomeIEnumerable.Select(MyFunctionThatTakesAnItemInTheIEnumerable)`

Comment: @CharlesLambert Inference in `var foo = SomeIEnumerable.Select(sie => sie.SomeProperty)` works because of the return type of `sie.SomeProperty` lambda, i.e. the return type of the supplied function. Trying to infer based on the return type of the method would be something like this: `Func<Func<Foo,string>,string> funcA = ValueOrDefault(toSave, fromDb, string.IsNullOrEmpty);` i.e. explicitly telling the compiler the return type that you expect (and it does not work either).

Comment: I see, in my code, the return type of the method is not declared in the body of the generic function. Even though `Predicate<T>` is supplied and called in the function, it does not supply the return type, it only returns `bool`.